# What does docker mean when it says "Memory limited without swap"

Tags: docker

I'm getting a warning when I run docker:

> WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap.

I'm trying to work out what this means, particularly the phrase "Memory limited without swap."

Does this mean that the container can use more memory than you would normally allow it by using the swap space of the host machine? Or does it mean that the container can't use the swap space, even when the host runs out of memory completely? Is it caused by having no swap space configured? Is it irrelevant if you aren't using swap anyway?

Note: I'm not interested in how to fix it - there are lots of results about that on google. I'm interested in what it *means*, and why it matters.

Comment: Maybe need to `enable cgroup swapping` on the host machine, check this link: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/docker/how-to-limit-memory-and-cpu-for-docker-containers/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Docker daemon relies on the following virtual files to implement memory and swap limits:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes
```

If your kernel does not support swap memory limit, the second file won't be there, and `docker run` won't impose any limitations on the use of the swap space. That way the container is even allowed to use more swap than the `-m, --memory` setting, as if `--memory-swap` had been set to `-1`. Obviously, the container can't use more swap space than you have configured on your system.

However, the warning message is also trying to say that option `-m, --memory` will still take effect, and the maximum amount of user memory (including file cache) will be set as intended.

---

The mentioned cgroup mount point may differ, consult `/proc/self/mounts`.

Comment: "the option --memory-swap has no effect" - Do you mean the container can use all the swap it wants, as if you had set `--memory-swap -1`? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details

This is presumably a problem if you have 2 containers that want lots of memory - they will both use lots of swap until there is none left and one of them will die?

Comment: @rjmunro I corrected the answer. As to the 2 container problem, I don't know if the kernel ends up choosing one of the 2 containers to kill as a victim or it picks some other random process.

Answer (score 21):

Here's what I found.

Swap isn't used by default. You can check this on Ubuntu/Debian containers at `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat`. Check the [swap value](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt), you'll see it's set to 0 (bytes). No swap usage.

You can [enable and limit swap usage](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details) with the `--memory` and `--memory-swap` flags typically, and here's where this WARNING seems like it would get you. From [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-swap-limit-capabilities) regarding a very similar warning:

> If you don’t need these capabilities, you can ignore the warning. You can enable these capabilities on Ubuntu or Debian by following these instructions.

tl;dr: swap is disabled by default. If the cgroup is disabled or container swap limits are otherwise compromised like this warning indicates, you won't be able to set those limits.

Comment: Be aware that: "Memory and swap accounting incur an overhead of about 1% of the total available memory and a 10% overall performance degradation, even if Docker is not running." So, enable it if you really need.

Answer (score 14):

For above issue, Docker installation on Ubuntu 16.04 we not be capable of
setting limits. This is because cgroups swapping is disabled by default.

When attempting to set limits you will be given the following error.

> root@ubuntuserver:~# docker container run -d -ti --hostname testcontainer --
> name testubuntu2 --restart=always --memory="50m" --memory-swap=0 --cpus="0.5"
> ubuntu:16.04
> WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is
> not mounted. Memory limited without swap.
> 1fb75aba88e61cf4ca7c96fdd6db939b474d80c0d923233bcb176bf81224dc44
> root@ubuntuserver:~#

In order resolve the above issue, update the grub file with below entry:

```
root@ubuntuserver:~# fgrep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Now update-grub:

```
root@ubuntuserver:~# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-74-generic
done
root@ubuntuserver:~#
```

Reboot machine once has done and create container with memory limit:

```
root@ubuntuserver:~# docker container run -d -ti --hostname testcontainer -- 
name testubuntu2 --restart=always --memory="50m" --memory-swap=0 --cpus="0.5" 
ubuntu:16.04
93969354be0445f3458999259747d82231b4084728c3ccf8801dc89be8aadaa3
root@ubuntuserver:~#
```

Comment: Yes, but what would the consequences of not "fixing" this be?
Pls answer the OP question :v
(I want to know too)

Comment: And also, why is this not set like that by default? What are the downsides of "fixing" this?

Comment: there is a comment below suggesting that fixing this causes a small memory hit and a bigger performance hit. i have no experience personally.

Answer (score 5):

One impact of fixing this warning is stated in the [docker post-install documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/):

> Memory and swap accounting incur an overhead of about 1% of the total available memory and a 10% overall performance degradation, even if Docker is not running.

> If you don’t need these capabilities, you can ignore the warning.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28844053/2550406) states

> cgroup swap limit is important if you are using swap and want to enforce memory limit that includes both memory and swap.

That sounds to me like the warning means that a container could still use "unlimited" amounts of memory. Once it reaches the imposed `--memory=` limit, it starts swapping to swap space. And if that is full, it stops. But by "fixing" this warning, we would also be able to give it limited swap space.
That would be useful in the case where we need to guarantee available swap space to other programs as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for Docker is the following:

On your docker build machine, create a `sysctl.conf` file with the following entry:

```
vm.nr_hugepages=128
```

(128 is what I chose, you can change accordingly)

Next in your Dockerfile - add the following into the process.

```
COPY /folderlocation/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This will copy the `sysctl` file into the correct directory in the docker image.

This worked for my docker XMRig solution.

Comment: As I say in the question: I'm not interested in how to fix it - there are lots of results about that on google. I'm interested in what it means, and why it matters.

Comment: Could be interesting for those of us who want a fix ;-)

Comment: If You are interested in an answer to a different question you should ask a different question. The question is clearly about the meaning and implications of the message and the mechanism of swapping etc. Not about how to enable one setting or another.

Answer (score 1):

If you're *not* using swap, and are just concerned about **RAM** limits, I can confirm that on ubuntu 18.04, processes within a container will be killed off once its specified memory limit is reached, even without the kernel settings.

In my test where I exec'd into the container alongside its normal processes and ran something memory-intensive, just the large process was killed off: I was expecting the whole container to be restarted.  This was in docker swarm using resource limits set in the compose file.

I don't know whether cgroup_enable=memory would make this better in some way... Perhaps it would cause the combined memory of all processes in the container to be monitored as a group more efficiently?

Answer (score -8):

It may be because you used the -m flag here:

```
docker build \
  --build-arg commit_datavana="$commit_sha" \
  --build-arg CACHE_BUST="$(date)" \
  -m 8g \     # hurrrr
  -t "$name_tag" .
```

maybe remove the `-m` flag if it's not needed

Comment: Question is about the message due to **-m** and continue to use it.  Question is also about how to resolve the warning that is reported by docker.